# How to fix error when building the android apk with svg file in assets directory

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg

I used to react-native-svg-uri plugin until the illustrate images with SVG's format in app, but when I want to build the apk in the project, occur error and tell the change SVG's format to png or jpeg. how to fix this problem?

Comment: WHat's your minimum API level?  Android only supports svg as of 21.  Support in versions below that requires additional work/technique at the java level, does your RN plugin use that, or does it only work when its built in?